# how to update in one php with different field and values in PHP

Tags: php, updates

I have many forms, can I use one PHP file to update all of it or should I make a different file for each? but if that so the file will be too many
can anyone help?

Comment: Could u provide more details about ur question like code snippets, screenshots or images would be helpful to get answer quickly

Comment: depends, if it's the same code but uses slightly different variables (like table name, field names etc.) then make one function to update and then call it passing in the different fields / table names / other vars.

Answer (score 0):

That's your choice.

If it's possible to select the appropriate piece of code for each form sended in one file, you can do so (e.g. use the submit-value of the input-field [type submit] or add a name and a value attribute to buttons). Maybe you save some boilerplait-code this way.

On the other hand, seperate files could give you a better oveview, allow better maintance (maybe), etc.

Have a look of the projects size/complexity and decide what is more important.